# Difference between np.nan and np.NaN

Tags: arrays, numpy, nan

Is there any difference between np.Nan and np.nan? As per my understanding both are  used for null values but if you look here

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,2,np.nan,0],[3,4,np.nan,1],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5]],columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
print(np.nan == np.NaN)
```

I get following output:

```
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now if these are same `print(np.nan == np.NaN)` should return `True` and why are the values in dataframe populated as `NaN`?

I get `NaN` is not a number so it might be treating it that way and hence changing the entry in dataframe but I am still not sure.

Comment: np.nan is np.NaN is True. They are alias.

Comment: In pycharm, I get false.

Comment: @user10089194 You should not use equality to test `nan`s, it will always return False. i.e. `np.nan == np.nan` is also `False`. But testing identity with `is`, `np.nan is np.NaN` is `True`. See [IEEE 754 Floating Point Special Values](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/misc.html#ieee-754-floating-point-special-values) in the NumPy docs.

Comment: `both are used for null values` - no. Not null. "Not a number".

Comment: Note that `NaN ≠ NaN` holds in any IEEE 754 compliant floating-point system. So you will find this behaviour almost anywhere you look, not just in Python. This goes all the way down to the CPU level.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so basically
`NaN`,`NAN` and `nan` are equivalent definitions of nan

or in other words

`NaN` and `NAN` are aliases of `nan`

```
np.nan
np.NaN
np.NAN
```

if you will check the equality of these it returns `False`

and if you check the types of all these 3 then you will find that all are of same `type(float)`

but let

```
a=np.NaN
b=np.NAN
c=np.nan
```

now if you will check the equality of a,b and c it returns `True` **(it won't work now)**

Even in the documentation(line 4) it is said that:-

**cannot use equality to test NaNs**

you can check the documentation from here:-

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html?highlight=numpy%20nan

Comment: Actually, `a == b` returns `False` as well. Likewise for `c`.

Answer (score 2):

- When you try: `np.nan is np.NAN is np.NaN`, you will get `true`
- I have searched the offical doc of numpy , it says:

  - IEEE 754 floating point representation of Not a Number (NaN).
    **NaN and NAN are equivalent definitions of nan. Please use nan instead of NaN**.
  - IEEE 754 floating point representation of Not a Number (NaN).
    **NaN and NAN are equivalent definitions of nan. Please use nan instead of NAN**.

Answer (score 1):

actually even if you test:
`np.nan == np.nan`
you would get
`false`